# Do I need a docker-machine with dlite?

Tags: docker

this is my first day with docker so, I might be missing something in the installation process.

I'm running OSX 10.11.3 (15D21) and installed dlite (v. 1.1.4) via homebrew with:

```
$brew install docker dlite
$sudo dlite install
$dlite start
```

but when I'm trying to boot postgis image there is an error:

```
$docker run mdillon/postgis:9.5
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
```

I had a hope that with DLite installation process will be simplified, but, maybe it still depends on the docker-machine or other extra?

Comment: Can you check that there is a file at /var/run/docker.sock, and that the DOCKER_HOST environment variable is not set.

Comment: docker.sock is present... but what service created it?
`srwxrwxrwx  1 root  daemon  0 Mar 27 19:15 /var/run/docker.sock`.
DOCKER_HOST is empty (echo $DOCKER_HOST)

Comment: You may also be interested in https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/, which was just announced

Comment: I'm, waiting for invite!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just wasn't running `sudo dlite daemon`

Comment: Fellow reviewers: seems to me this _is_ an answer - the OP explaining what was wrong.